# Disable click handler on specific cells in GWT CellTable

Tags: java, gwt, celltable

I'm writing a webapp with GWT for the first time.  The app includes a grid with rows that, when clicked, will show a more detailed description of the row's contents.  I managed to add the click handler into the table, but some columns had dropdowns or checkboxes, and now when I try to click those elements, the click handler overrides them.  I need to know if I can selectively disable the click handler for those types of elements.  My code is below:

```
public void onCellPreview(CellPreviewEvent event)
        {
            if(event.getNativeEvent().getType().contains("click")){
                String[] test = { "test", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5" };
                EditDialog popup = new EditDialog(Table.this, test);
                popup.show();
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
if(event.getNativeEvent().getType().contains("click")){
    // if you don't need this event)
    event.setCanceled(true);
    // otherwise continue
    ...
}
```

Comment: This works to the extent that the dropdown and checkbox are now opening/functioning, which they weren't before, but it is still followed up by the pop-up automatically opening after the one click.

Comment: I should also note that switching it to a double-click event would also be acceptable if that's easier, but I'm uncertain how to do that as well.

Comment: Check which column was clicked. If the column does not need a popup, don't show it.

Comment: Thanks! I actually wound up changing it to a double click using addDomHandler anyway, but I'll probably use this in the near future anyway.